# How do I reorder columns for all data frames in a list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I already have a list of data frames (mylist) and need to switch the first and second column for all the data frames in the list.

### Test Data Frame in List

```
[reads] [phylum]
1         phylum1
2         phylum2
3         phylum3
```

---

Into....

```
[phylum] [reads]
phylum1      1
phylum2      2
phylum3      3
```

I know I need to use lapply, but not sure what to input for the FUN=

`mylist <- lapply(mylist, FUN = mylist[ ,c("phylum", "reads")])`

errors saying incorrect number of dimensions

Sorry if this is a simple question and thanks in advance for your help!

-Brand new R user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FUN` asks for a function that it can apply to every element in the list. You are passing `mylist[ ,c("phylum", "reads")])` which is not a function.

```
# sample data
df1 <- data.frame(reads = sample(10,4), phylum = sample(10,4))
df2 <- data.frame(reads = sample(10,4), phylum = sample(10,4))
df3 <- data.frame(reads = sample(10,4), phylum = sample(10,4))
df4 <- data.frame(reads = sample(10,4), phylum = sample(10,4))

ldf <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
ldf_re <- lapply(ldf, FUN = function(X){X[c('phylum', 'reads')]})
```

In the last line, the `lapply` will iterate through all the dataframes, they will be passed as the `X` argument for the function defined in the `FUN` argument and the columns will be dataframes will be stored in the list `ldf_re` with their columns rearranged.

Comment: Thank you so much- I understand the difference between FUN and function in this case now.  Its good to know I was at least close

Comment: Glad to help. :)